# Can I grep/awk/sed a line for multiple matches in a single line and get the info after it?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I get files that come in from an external source that are unordered... and contain bits of info I'm interested in and some that I'm not.

```
name: myName var1: xxx var2: bbbb
var1: xxx var2: aaaa name: myName
name: myName var1: yyy var2: bbbb
var1: xxx var2: aaaa name: myName
name: myName var1: yyy var2: aaaa
var2: aaaa name: myName var1: xxx 
name: myName var1: zzz var2: bbbb
var2: aaaa name: myName var1: zzz
```

What'd I'd like to output are just the values related to `var1` and `var2` and ordered so that `var1` is first. Like so:

```
xxx bbbb
xxx aaaa
yyy bbbb
xxx aaaa
yyy aaaa
xxx aaaa
zzz bbbb
zzz aaaa
```

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in `awk`:

```
awk '{
        v1 = v2 = ""
        for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
                if ($i == "var1:") v1 = $(i+1)
                if ($i == "var2:") v2 = $(i+1)
        }
        print v1, v2
     }'
```

For each line, it tests all the odd-numbered fields (`$1`, `$3` and `$5`)
for being `var1:` or `var2:`, and, if matched,
copies the value (from the next field, `$(i+1)`,
which becomes `$2`, `$4` or `$6`) to `v1` or `v2`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, creating a hash from the key-value pairs:

```
$ perl -alnE 'my %h = @F; say "$h{qw(var1:)} $h{qw(var2:)}"' file
xxx bbbb
xxx aaaa
yyy bbbb
xxx aaaa
yyy aaaa
xxx aaaa
zzz bbbb
zzz aaaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it multiple ways, two of them being as shown below:

```
$ perl -lne 'print /(?=.*var1:\h+(\H+))(?=.*var2:(\h+\H+))/' input.file


$ sed -e '
     H;s/.*//;x
     s/.*[[:space:]]var2: \([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)/\1 &/
     s/.*[[:space:]]var1: \([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)/\1 &/
     s/ \n.*//
' input.file
```

With the features in `GNU sed`, we can simplify quite a bit :

```
$ sed -Ee ' 
    s/^/\n/
    s/.*\svar2: (\S+)/\1 &/
    s/.*\svar1: (\S+)/\1 &/
    s/ \n.*//
' input.file
```

Output:

```
xxx bbbb
xxx aaaa
yyy bbbb
xxx aaaa
yyy aaaa
xxx aaaa
zzz bbbb
zzz aaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

your data in dat, use gnu sed;

```
$ sed -E 's/.*var1:\s(\S+).+var2:\s(\S+).*|.*var2:\s(\S+).+var1:\s(\S+).*/\1\4 \2\3/' dat
```